# PDF to image converter that acts like making a screenshot of a PDF reader

Tags: linux, pdf, images, file-converter

I would like to use a PDF file as screensaver on Linux. For that purpose I thought of converting the single pages of a PDF file to images and giving these to an image-slideshow screensaver. But of course there's the problem of quality. For now I've actually only tried 'convert' from Imagemagick like this:

```
convert -density 300 -alpha remove -resize <screen resolution> <pdf file> test-%02d.png
```

But everything looks a bit blurry in the PNG file, unlike if I open the PDF in a PDF reader like xpdf. The conversion takes very long, too, while the reader opens in a second. I think it's due to rasterization. So I thought, I would need a converter that renders the PDF to one specific resolution, like a PDF reader does, but saving the output to a file instead of displaying it.

Am I right with this assumption?
Have you any idea of a tool that can do this job?
Of course, I prefer open-source software, but I'm interested in any suggestions.